# Replace a character in a string with another string without using built in functions

Tags: c, string

I have two strings. `s={"Mangalore"}` and `p={"Man"}`. Iwant to replace every occurance of `'a'` with string `"man"`. i.e. 
input: Mangalore
output: MManngManlore
I tried this program. But I'm stuck at one point. Here my *function*:

```
string_replace(char *s,char *p)
{
 char t[25];
 int i,j,len1,len2;
 len1=strlen(s);
 len2=strlen(p);
 for(i=0;i<len1;i++)
 {
  if(s[i]=='a')
   {
     for(j=0;j<len2;j++)
       t[i+j]=p[j];
    }
    else
     {
      t[i]=s[i];
     }
  }
}
```

My doubt is in the statement `t[i]=s[i];`. What i need to write in place of this. Please help me. I need to write it without using built in functions.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: `strlen()` is a 'built in' ;-)

Comment: The `t[i]=s[i]` part is ok... but in the part above it, when `s[i]` is 'a', you need to increase `i` to account for the fact you're writing three chars instead of one. And you'll need separate index vars for `s` and `t` since the index in one increases more than the other when you do the substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one more variable k. which is initially k=i; then after the for loop,

```
if(s[i]=='a')
   {
     for(j=0;j<len2;j++)
       t[i+j]=p[j];
```

add

```
k=k+j
```

and increment k with i in outer for loop.
this is because making t[i]=s[i] results in making t[]=s[] so no changes to the array. so change it to

```
t[k]=s[i]
```

the full code can be like,

```
for(i=0,k=0;i<len1;i++,k++)
 {
  if(s[i]=='a')
   {
     for(j=0;j<len2;j++)
       t[k+j]=p[j];
     k=k+j;
    }
    else
     {
      t[k]=s[i];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe it would be `t[k+j]=p[j]` in the loop above then.

Comment: @Codor No in that statement not needed. i updated answer to include code check it. anyway thanks.

Comment: @sangeetha you trace be prgram for input. you can understand why the statements are used. trace using string as array of characters and see how indexes increase. it can give you better understanding of string manipulation.

Comment: @sangeetha read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about). accept the one answer whichever solved your problem and upvote the once that were usefull.

Comment: Thank you LearningC. Your answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

The length of the result `t` can be longer than the length of the input, so just using a fixed length of 25 for the output might not be a good idea. Indeed the statement `t[i]=s[i]` is problematic, as the index for the result `t` eventually needs to be larger. I suggest using an additional variable to keep track of the next position of `t` to write to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the characters in the buffer pointed to by `s`.

```
#define MAX_LEN

string_replace(char *s, char *p) {
    char t[MAX_LEN];
    char ch = 'a';  // char to be replaced by string pointed to by p
    while(*s) {
        if(*s == ch) {
            while(*p)
                *t++ = *p++;  // copy the string pointed to by p to t
        }
        else
            *t++ = *s++;   // copy the characters of s to t which are not ch
    }
    *t = '\0';   // append the null byte to t to make it a string
}
```